# Why I can't import Charles proxy certificate on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I can't import Charles 4.6.3 certificate on Linux Mint.

When I try to import Charles certificate, the "import" button is not clickable.

Button in red box is an import button:
[image: button in red box is an import button]

I went to [chls.pro/ssl.](https://chls.pro/ssl.) and downloaded .pem certificate. Then, I moved it to:

> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

And ran this command:

> sudo update-ca-certificates

And get it:

> Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
> 0 added, 0 removed; done.
> Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
> done.
> done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Mint manpages online, but (LTS = jammy) Ubuntu is close enough [and it says](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html)

```
   Furthermore  all  certificates  with  a  .crt  extension  found below /usr/local/share/ca-
   certificates are also included as implicitly trusted.
```

Notice the words "with a .crt extension". A file name something.pem will be ignored, and that's exactly what you got -- "0 added".

Comment: I have added .crt certificate, console says:


Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping ca-certificates.crt,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
rehash: warning: skipping charles.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
1 added, 0 removed; done.

Adding debian:charles.pem
done.

Importing into legacy system store:
I already trust 124, your new list has 124
Import process completed.

Importing into BTLS system store:
I already trust 124, your new list has 124
Import process completed.
Done
done.

Comment: It sounds like you put ca-certificates.crt in the directory, which does have a suitable name but wrong CONTENTS. Instead, you should put a file _containing the Charles root cert_ -- it should be only one cert -- in a file _named_ with .crt -- in other words, rename charles.pem to charles.crt .